Що означає "наскільки" в даному контексті?

Наскільки так вважають від непорозуміння, їхнє незнання легко зцілити (адже заперечення має бути не проти їхнього логосу, а проти міркування) наскільки ж говорять заради логосу, зцілення таких людей - це викриття їхнього логосу в звуках та словах.

і ось переклад того самого речення англійською

Those who have been driven to this position by
difficulties in their thinking can easily be cured of their
ignorance; for it is not their expressed argument but their
thought that one has to meet. But those who argue for the sake
of argument can be cured only by refuting the argument as
expressed in speech and in words.

Чому було використано саме слово "наскільки" ? Мені тут здається логічнішим "оскільки".

Це якійсь дуже літературний переклад.
